# Symbol to proc for two items rather than one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do this a lot:

```
m51.items.map(&:id)
```

but would like to do two elements for my symbol-to-proc. What would be the syntax? I tried

```
m51.items.map(&[:instore_image_url, :id])
```

but it is not working. It's a RoR app so if Rails specific, that's OK.

Comment: no way to do this. you're stuck with `m51.items.map { |item| [item.instore_image_url, item.id] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mapping to proc will only ever map to one method. You can't pass it an array.
You have a couple of options:

Use the non-proc-version of map:

```
m51.items.map {|i| [i.instore_image_url, i.id] }
```

or create a new method on your item that returns two things and call that:

```
# preferably give it a more meaningful name than this
def url_and_id
  [self.instore_image_url, self.id]
end

m51.items.map(&:url_and_id)
```

Comment: Geez, almost asked the same question and this came up via Google search lol. Used the second part of your answer

Comment: google and Stack overflow... saving the time of programmers the world over ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious reason why `Symbol#to_proc` isn't working, is because you are trying to convert an `Array` to a `Proc`, not a `Symbol`. So, you need a suitable `Array#to_proc`. Something like this:

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    -> el { map(&el.method(:public_send)) }
  end
end

Item = Struct.new(:instore_image_url, :id, :doesnt_matter)

items = [Item.new('foo.jpg', 23, :bla), Item.new('bar.gif', 42, :blub)]

items.map(&[:instore_image_url, :id])
# => [['foo.jpg', 23], ['bar.gif', 42]]
```

However, that's a really bad idea. It's not clear exactly, what `Array#to_proc` is supposed to mean. There are a few implementations of `Array#to_proc` in the wild, but most of them interpret `&[:one, :two]` as `_.one.two`, and not `[_.one, _.two]`. Mathematically speaking, an `Array` is isomorphic to a function from `Integer`s to elements, so the only obvious implementation that makes sense is this:

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    method(:[]).to_proc
  end
end

[2, 2, -1, 0, 0].map(&[:one, :two, :three])
# => [:three, :three, :three, :one, :one]
```

Comment: thx, love the hack on Array - would be kinda a good interview question but pretty opaque for code. Very helpful explanation and I hope everything is well.